# Define time intervals using day of week/month (ISO 8601?)

Tags: date, datetime, iso8601, dateinterval, datetimeformatinfo

I want to define time intervals like:

- Each week, from Monday 12:00 a.m. to Sunday 11:59:59 p.m.
- Each day from 12:00 a.m. to 11:59:59 p.m.
- Each month from the first day of the month 12:00 a.m. to the last day of the month 11:59:59 p.m.

Is this possible using ISO 8601, or any other well-known standard?

Comment: What is your question again?

Comment: You are likely to need [iCal](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545).  The recurring representations in ISO 8601 are not as comprehensive as those in iCal.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking for repeating periods of a week, a day and a month.  The period should be defined as P1W, P1D or P1M respectively.  Given an appropriate start point, I'd expect things such as the following to work:

R/2015-02-16/P1W - repeating weekly periods, starting on a known Monday.

R/2015-02-17/P1D - repeating daily periods, starting today

R/2015-02/P1M - repeating monthly periods, starting this month

These should be ISO 8601 compliant.